# 'Command errored out with exit status 1' getting this error message while installing mysql client in python

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
(env) C:\Users\shreya kumar\Documents\django website\audit_website>pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz (87 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for mysqlclient, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\shreya kumar\documents\django website\env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\shreya kumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7l4hf6a3\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\shreya kumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7l4hf6a3\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\shreya kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-npl_lx21\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\shreya kumar\documents\django website\env\include\site\python3.9\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\shreya kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7l4hf6a3\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\shreya kumar\documents\django website\env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\shreya kumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7l4hf6a3\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\shreya kumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7l4hf6a3\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\shreya kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-npl_lx21\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\shreya kumar\documents\django website\env\include\site\python3.9\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\shreya kumar\documents\django website\env\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(env) C:\Users\shreya kumar\Documents\django website\audit_website>
```

Comment: Did you already try installing the software it says to install in the error message?

Comment: it's impossible to read, please edit and add more informations.

Comment: Python 3.9 is new, so there aren't any official wheels yet. If you use 64-bit Python 3.8.X, then `pip install mysqlclient` should install a wheel without any problems. If you must use Python 3.9, then you'll have to install `mysqlclient` from source, which is harder.